# Makefile ifeq not behaving

Tags: makefile

I have a very simple makefile as follows

```
FRUIT = apple orange

all : $(FRUIT)

$(FRUIT) : 
ifeq ($(@),apple)
    @echo "APPLE!"
else
    @echo "ORANGE!"
endif
```

When I execute

```
make all
```

I see

```
ORANGE!
ORANGE!
```

I have checked my tabbing and I believe my spacing on ifeq is correct. What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ifeq` is evaluated when the Makefile is first parsed, not when the individual recipe is executed. At that point, `$(@)` is always the empty string.

You can perform the same logic in shell script in the recipe itelf.

```
$(FRUIT):
    case $@ in apple) echo "APPLE!";; *) echo "ORANGE!";; asac
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional directives are expanded as soon as make reads them, long before the recipe is executed. `$@`expands to the empty string when make parses that line so you always end up with the `else` part of the conditional.

Just use something like the following instead:

```
FRUIT = apple orange

all: $(FRUIT)

$(FRUIT):
    @echo "$@!"
```

If you need separate recipes then write them

```
apple:
    @echo "APPLE!"

orange:
    @echo "ORANGE!"
```